# Enabling Interrupts in U-boot for ARM cortex A-9

Tags: arm, interrupt-handling, interrupt, u-boot

I am trying to configure a GPIO interrupt in the uboot, This it to test the Interrupt response time without any OS intervention (Bare-metal). I was able to configure the pin-muxing and also successful in setting up the interrupt with the GPIO pin.

My question is regarding the registering of the interrupt service routine. I see that the Interrupt vector table for my platform is at address 0xFFFF0000 ( I read the System Control Register to find out this). The interrupt Id for the GPIO was 56 and with that i just calculated the address where my interrupt service routine should reside and just tried writing the address with the pointer to my ISR routine. Is this the right way of doing it? or i have to take care of the all the other things like context saving etc by myself?

Note : I am using an ARM Cortex A-9.

Edit :

Based on the answers i went through the code i have the following questions. The definition of

do_irq for my architecture( arm v7) is not doing much and the CONFIG_USE_IRQ does not work for me since functions like arch_interrupt_init are not defined for me. So i can conclude interrupts are not supported for my architecture. Now If i have to define this on my own what all functions i need to implement to get this working? Since this is a very small part of my proj and i would want to see if i can do this is feasible to implement. I just want to know if this requires few lines of code or requires some effort to implement this interrupt support.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ARM vectors all interrupts to address `0xFFFF0018` (or `0x00000018`).  This is typically an unconditional *branch*.  Then the code will inspect some *interrupt controller* hardware to determine the number **56**.  Typically, there is a routine to set the handler for the interrupt number, so you don't manually patch the code; this table is dependent on how the `u-boot` interrupt handling is implemented.

In my `u-boot` source<sup>note</sup>, the interrupt table looks like this,

```
.globl _start
_start:
    b       reset
    ldr     pc, _undefined_instruction
    ldr     pc, _software_interrupt
    ldr     pc, _prefetch_abort
    ldr     pc, _data_abort
    ldr     pc, _not_used
    ldr     pc, _irq
    ldr     pc, _fiq
...
_irq:
        .word irq
```

So `_irq` is a label to install a routine for interrupt handling; it does some assembler in the same file and then calls `do_irq()`, based on **CONFIG_USE_IRQ**.  Part of the API is  in *lib_arm/interrupts.c*.  Some **CPUs** are defined to handler *irqs*, such as *cpu/arm720t/interrupts.c*, for a S3C4510B.  Here you can see that the code gets a register from this controller and then branches to a table.

So by default `u-boot` doesn't seem to have support for *interrupts*.  This is not surprising as a boot loader is usually *polling* based for simplicity and speed.

**Note:** My `u-boot` is base on 2009.01-rc3.

Comment: Thank you. That helped. I have edited the question and would like to have your input. Thanks

Comment: @Nuetrino  Take a look at the file I referenced, *cpu/arm720t/interrupts.c* and maybe other files in that directory.  It does look like some **u-boot** platforms handle interrupts.  However, a larger question might be "Why do you need interrupts?".  Isn't it possible to *poll*, like other code probably does?  Sorry, I am not familiar with **u-boot**.  We used it early in a project and then wrote our own boot loader.

Comment: I am trying to measure response time of interrupts when run baremetal ( without any OS scheduler interference) so that i can put some values to a model. I do not need it for the application, That is the reason i asked the question on effort since i will have to decide whether it is worth implementing it. I will have a look thanks.

Comment: @Nuetrino  Sorry, you stated that at the top of your question.  However, the *interrupt response* is going to depend on the **u-boot** structure.  It is not actually the best for response.  It is a simplicity of implementation.  For instance, most *OS* must save all registers and possibly switch an MMU on a context flip.  Your model will match the *u-boot* model for interrupt handling; unless I don't understand how you measure.  Some SOC's have an IO for interrupt pending.  Toggle another IO at ISR start and you can see latency.

Comment: I modified the common/main.c file and just before showing the u-boot prompt i register for a interrupt on a GPIO pin and then in the ISR of this interrupt i will toggle another GPIO pin in this way i will measure the timing with a scope ( time between the interrupt generation which is a button press and toggle GPIO). My understanding is that without any  interference from other interrupts,kernel threads etc etc( which are introduced by the OS) I can get some understanding of the latency introduced by the hardware ( during interrupt handling).

Comment: Cont.. I also have measurements from SMP/AMP type systems to compare with. What do you think about this idea?

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Today i made it work and now i hope to measure some response time with the scope!