# what does label: .word label mean in ARM Assembly

Tags: assembly, arm

I am looking at the following sequence in uboot

```
.globl _start
_start: b   reset
    ldr pc, _undefined_instruction
    ldr pc, _software_interrupt
    ldr pc, _prefetch_abort
    ldr pc, _data_abort
    ldr pc, _not_used
    ldr pc, _irq
    ldr pc, _fiq
#ifdef CONFIG_SPL_BUILD
_undefined_instruction: .word _undefined_instruction
_software_interrupt:    .word _software_interrupt
_prefetch_abort:    .word _prefetch_abort
_data_abort:        .word _data_abort
_not_used:      .word _not_used
_irq:           .word _irq
_fiq:           .word _fiq
_pad:           .word 0x12345678 /* now 16*4=64 */
#else
_undefined_instruction: .word undefined_instruction
_software_interrupt:    .word software_interrupt
_prefetch_abort:    .word prefetch_abort
_data_abort:        .word data_abort
_not_used:      .word not_used
_irq:           .word irq
_fiq:           .word fiq
_pad:           .word 0x12345678 /* now 16*4=64 */
#endif  /* CONFIG_SPL_BUILD */
```

Now if there is an IRQ or a FIQ core will branch to _irq, but in one case it find _irq : .word _irq, What does this mean ?

Is the address of _irq a valid instruction in ARM ?
I am not able to understand this, can anyone explain ?

Comment: This is just an interrupt vector table, not executable code.

Comment: on interrupt this vector table would be used. Also see that there is a branch in the #if part of table

Comment: "ldr pc, _irq" : load pc with the value in addr _irq, and "_irq:  .word irq" : at addr _irq there is the value irq, which is the function pointer for irq routine. So when irq occurs pc jumps to irq routine. just to wrote down my understanding.

Answer (score 6):

`label: .word value` places the 4-byte `value` at the address assigned (by the linker) to `label`.

So `_irq: .word _irq` effectively places _irq's address *at* that address (e.g. if the address of the `_irq` label is 0x12345678 you'd get the value 0x12345678 at address 0x12345678).

Comment: right, so now if an interrupt comes what will happen a prefetch abort exception ? as the ADDR(_irq) is not an instruction

Comment: If I were to guess, I'd say that they've stripped out interrupt/exception handling for the SPL builds (due to size constaints) and are using the above vectors as a simple way of causing the CPU to crash/hang. I can't say for sure though, as I'm not familiar with uboot.

Comment: Look closely at the lack of an **underbar**.  `_irq: .word irq`.  They are not the same label.

Comment: @artlessnoise: As you can see, both variants are present in the code the OP posted (`_label: .word label` and `_label: .word _label`).

Comment: You are correct.  That will crash if `CONFIG_SPL_BUILD` is used and an interrupt is encountered.  I seem to remember that *u-boot* doesn't even use interrupts normally now that I think about it.  Here is [another question like that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15829601/enabling-interrupts-in-u-boot-for-arm-cortex-a-9) for the OP.  Some context from the OP would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You might be wondering this is kind of a recursive reference: why

```
.label: .word label?
```

Wouldn't they be the same? In fact, the .label is just a directive for the compiler, but the 'label' following the .word is a function pointer, in this case, to the interruption function. I think it's more a compiler's trick. You can also do

```
ldr pc, =irq
```

to get the same result, where "ldr" here is also a directive rather than the arm instruction.

Comment: Yes, a good answer, but the difference is that you can write `*_irq = my_handler;` to update the address.  With `ldr pc, =irq` there is no way to change the vector.