# Handling gpio Interrupts in u-boot

Tags: arm, interrupt, interrupt-handling, u-boot

How can i know that my architecture support interrupts? If it supports then how can we implement a interrupt on some gpio pin? In my case some other board is sending interrupt on a gpio pin. can I detect this interrupt in u-boot level and process it in handler? i am using arm architecture.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Enabling Interrupts in U-boot for ARM cortex A-9](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15829601/enabling-interrupts-in-u-boot-for-arm-cortex-a-9)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer, interrupts are not really used in U-Boot.

[Ref1](http://lists.denx.de/pipermail/u-boot/2004-June/005913.html) Normally you don't need interrupts  in  U-Boot.  U-Boot  is  strictly
single-tasking  by  nature and design.

[Ref2](http://e2e.ti.com/support/embedded/linux/f/354/t/54162.aspx) All the peripherals are implemented in polled mode.

[Ref3](http://lists.denx.de/pipermail/u-boot/2004-September/007199.html) U-boot is polling by design (simplicity).

More good info here [Enabling Interrupts in U-boot for ARM cortex A-9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15829601/enabling-interrupts-in-u-boot-for-arm-cortex-a-9)