# What guarantees does the linux kernel give in terms of how long a process pauses?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

Say I'm running a program on a linux machine. I want to be able to give some guarantees about how it will perform. In order to do this, I need to know if the linux kernel gives any guarantees about my process. This is in the same area as timeouts from gc pauses, i.e. when the process stops responding for a while but later comes back online.

Does the linux kernel give any guarantees about for how long a process may be paused, i.e. not executing?

What if there are no processes with a higher priority than the program I'm interested in?

Comment: Linux is non real time. Need RTOS for deterministic responses http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362906/how-real-time-is-linux-2-6

Comment: The kernel gives the guarantee that a process is paused at least as long as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know Linux does not give any guarantees on anything,

But if it is about your system running out of resources and pausing a process it will depend on the hardware running it.

If your process is the highest is will run unless instructed overwise,

I have never tested this but i beleive you can keep a process paused for as long as you want if you choose to.

Hope this Helped :)